# I am clicking on the message button in linkedin using selenium but cannot got the buttons

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am clicking on a button in linkedin using selenium with python but cann't get the exact thing.
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys
import csv
import os



login_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/rm/sign-in-another-account?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin'
base_url = ""
chrome_driver_path = '/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver'
names = []
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

# default login credential and search query
username = 'danishkhankd237@gmail.com'
password = 'dankhanish446'

results = []

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # retrive url in headless browser
    driver.get(login_url)
    
    # find search box
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_key']")))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_password']")))
   
    
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("email")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("password")
    
    # target button
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']")))
    searchbox.clear()
  
    base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=web%20scraping&network=%5B%22F%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH'
    
    driver.get(base_url)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".entity-result__divider .artdeco-button--secondary")

    
    for i in buttons:
       print('\nhhh', i.text)
    
    
    all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
    message_buttons = [btn  for btn in all_buttons if btn.text == "Message" ]
    print('\nhh',message_buttons)
    message_buttons[0].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    
    
    driver.close()


    And the output is :
   
hh []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkdn1.py", line 69, in <module>
    message_buttons[0].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand what is error as i have full excess to xpath and css of the button element.
Please specify where is the problem and how can i access to the button which is 'Message'
I have tried many techniques like by css selectors, by xpath, by tag , by contains text= 'Mesage'
etc but cann't got the thing.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Every button element as you located by `.entity-result__divider .artdeco-button--secondary` are actually containing inner `span` element while span is containing `Message` text.
So the button elements themselves are containing extra space   in addition to the `Message` text.
That's why `if btn.text == "Message"` returns false.
You should use `"Message" in btn.text` instead of `btn.text == "Message"` here.
i.e.
`[btn  for btn in all_buttons if "Message" in btn.text ]`
BTW, don't show your real email and password...

Comment: He already changed password. I tested it :)

Comment: But no reaction. Did my answer help or not, something additional? Nothing.

Comment: Don't hurry, maybe he will be back later.

Comment: Sure.  ;) Thanks

Comment: But how i use contains

Comment: It cann't resolve my problem as i cann't get to the button tags which has message text